Help please ... No possibility to withdraw tokens (100% fees)
I humbly come to you to see if a solution can be found to my issue.
A token (DAPPOS) has been promoted with official marketing data from the official token (links, websites, partnership, pictures, ...) and the token had the same name. After few researchs, it seemed to me and decided to buy some tokens.
Token contract:
0xc1f73d7cd5b3dccff3fdc224404ad51aa2b0ce94
Today I decided to check if I could withdraw some money to recoup the initial funds and I'd a surprise to see on the Uniswap app that the token DAPPOS was taking 100% fees on the transaction, meaning 0 money for me.
I decided to test with a small amount and got a warning from my Metamask to set up a custom spending cap. I put a small token (5USD) to check and nothing happened on my side despite an activity in my Metamask stating that a spending approval was approved to DAPPOS.
Has someone faced the same scam ? Is there any solution to recoup my funds ?
I was aware of some scams but this is totally new to me, and any help would be very much appreciated.
Thank you in advance,
C.

It is very likely it is a scam. There isn't any real token involved they want to scam you sending them some before ignoring you.

Unfortunately, once you've interacted with such a token, there may not be much that can be done to recoup your funds.

hello facing the same issue. i think we got scammed.
